# Error in downloading data using API (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api, python-requests

I am trying to download a dataset using the following code from a publicly available platform that was used before for the same purpose. However, I am not sure why I get this error, that is, whether because of an error in code or some changes in the website's (hatebase) API. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you.

```
import json 
import requests
import pandas as pd
from hatebase import HatebaseAPI

key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" # this is the key
filepath = "/dictionary.csv"  

hatebase = HatebaseAPI({"key": key})
filters = {"language": "eng"}
format = "json"
# initialize list for all vocabulary entry dictionaries
eng_vocab = []
response = hatebase.getVocabulary(filters=filters, format=format)
pages = response["number_of_pages"]
# fill the vocabulary list with all entries of all pages
# this might take some time...
for page in range(1, pages+1):
    filters["page"] = str(page) 
    response = hatebase.getVocabulary(filters=filters, format=format)
    eng_vocab.append(response["result"])

# create empty pandas df for all vocabulary entries
df_eng_vocab = pd.DataFrame()
# fill df
for elem in eng_vocab:
    df_eng_vocab = df_eng_vocab.append(elem)
# reset the df index
df_eng_vocab.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
# saving the file to csv
df_eng_vocab.to_csv(filepath)
```

The error I get is the following

```
Please check your API-Key, Authentication did nod respond with a token.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-de9970a761e5> in <module>
      7 #filepath = "/dictionary.csv" 
      8 
----> 9 hatebase = HatebaseAPI({"key": key})
     10 filters = {"language": "eng"}
     11 format = "json"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hatebase\__init__.py in __init__(self, settings)
     37             self.debug = settings["debug"]
     38 
---> 39         self.authenticate()
     40 
     41     def authenticate(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hatebase\__init__.py in authenticate(self)
     57             print("Please check your API-Key, Authentication did nod respond with a token.")
     58 
---> 59         if token is not None:
     60             self.token = response.json()["result"]["token"]
     61         else:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'token' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: it seems module has bug - author forgot to create variable `token` with default value `None`. OR maybe it couldn't get token from server and it didn't set default value `token = None`. Porbably you will have to digg in source code to check `token`. OR if this module has GitHub then check on GitHub if it has some fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After checking source code I found that you can set [current version](https://github.com/hatebase/Hatebase-API-Docs) to resolve problem

```
hatebase = HatebaseAPI({"key": key, "version": "4-4"})
```

---

**ORIGINAL VERSION:**

I registerd on [Hatebase.org](https://hatebase.org/) to get `API Key` but I didn't select `price plan`.

---

I took [source code](https://github.com/DanielJDufour/hatebase/blob/master/hatebase/__init__.py) and added `print()` in function `authenticate()` to see `JSON data from server

```
    print(response.json())

    try:
        token = response.json()["result"]["token"]
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Please check your API-Key, Authentication did nod respond with a token.")
```

and it shows this text somewhere in `JSON`

```
'The version of the API is now retired; 
 please update your queries to resume accessing the API'
```

Source code has line `version = '4-2'` but [documentation](https://github.com/hatebase/Hatebase-API-Docs) shows that current version is `4.4` so I changed into `version = '4-4'` and it stopped showing this error.

Because I didn't select `price plan` so now I get

```
'You must assign a plan to your account to access the API'
```

I will not select `price plan` so I don't know if it may need other changes.

---

You can copy source code with `class HatebaseAPI` to your file and change `version = '4-4'` and maybe it will works for you.

---

I sent this problem to author of the module as `issues` on GitHub: [newer API version - 4.4](https://github.com/DanielJDufour/hatebase/issues/3).
Maybe it will correct module (or not).

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the issue. I have now found a direct solution here: https://gist.github.com/noahgh221/68ae96c3f6dc41c9596fed704fdc454d which worked

Comment: after checking source code I found that you can run `HatebaseAPI({"key": key, 'version': '4-4'})`

Comment: Not actually. It still shows the same error.

Comment: it can show the same error with token but it may have different problem - and only text in JSON data could explain it . In my answer I had the same error with token but first because I had wrong version in code, and later because I didn't select `price plan`. Bot problems gives the same error but they need different changes.